# SVN update a working copy when parents are updated

Tags: svn, version-control

I have two SVN branches and I plan to partially copy the first working copy to another. I did this:

1. Libs /home/user/projects/libs/{lib1, lib2, lib3}
2. Core /home/user/projects/Apps/{libs,core}

```
    svn copy --parents /home/user/projects/libs/lib1/* /home/user/projects/Apps/libs/1
    svn copy --parents /home/user/projects/libs/lib2/* /home/user/projects/Apps/libs/2
    svn copy --parents /home/user/projects/libs/lib3/* /home/user/projects/Apps/libs/3
```

The question:
My peers are still working on /home/user/projects/libs/lib1, and when this repository is updated with new codes, I want my /home/user/projects/Apps/libs also updated. Is there any way to do that "automatically"?

I tried to do with the same svn copy command, and of course it fails with: 
svn: Path '/home/user/projects/Apps/libs/1' already exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only think on merge: `svn help merge`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I use svn:external setup for those libs repository. The only way to achieve the goal in question seems to merge the libs respectively.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't be updated automatically.

You may consider using `svn:externals` instead